# Why does memset fail in this case?

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation, memset

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int t;
    scanf("%d", &t);
    while(t--)
    {
        int *b1 = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*4);
        memset(b1, 0, sizeof(b1));
        cout<<"\nArray after memset:";
        for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
             printf("\t%d", b1[i]);
        for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
             scanf("%d", &b1[i]);
        free(b1);
    }
}
```

Input:
2
10
20
30
40
10
20
30
40

For the given input, the code gives the following output:

> Array after memset:    0   0   0   0
>
> Array after memset:    0   0   30  40

Why does memset fail in the second case?

(Also, I noticed that on removing the free(b1) statement, memset works fine).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sizeof(b1)` will return the size of `b1` and variable storing an integer pointer.

You want the size of the thing that it is pointing to - i.e. the parameter of `malloc` - `sizeof(int)*4`

Use that instead in `memset`

Also why are you using `scanf`, `malloc` in C++ code. Why not use `std::vector`?

Comment: Also not a good idea to mix `cout` and `printf`. THe buffering gets confusing for one

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
memset(b1, 0, sizeof(int)*4);
```

as `sizeof(int)*4` is the size of allocated memory block .